# Automated testing developer environments

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, continuous-integration, gradle

We use gradle as our build tool and use the idea plugin to be able to generate the project/module files.  The process for a new developer on the project would look like this:

- pull from source control.
- run 'gradle idea'.
- open idea and be able to develop without any further setup.

This all works nicely, but generally only gets exercised when a new developer joins or someone gets a new machine.  I would really like to automate the testing of this more frequently in the same way we automate our unit/integration tests as part of our continuous integration process.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if there is any libraries for doing this kind of thing?

You can also substitue idea for eclipse as we have a similar process for those that prefer using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The second step (with or without step one) is easy to smoke test (just execute the task as part of a CI build), the third one less so. However, if you are following best practices and regenerate IDEA files rather than committing them to source control, developers will likely perform both steps more or less regularly (e.g. every time a dependency changes).

Comment: I'm not sure what running the 2nd task in CI would give you. It will just generate a load of project files. It doesn't mean that opening them will allow you to run the project successfully.

Comment: It would prove that files can be generated without errors. "mean that opening them will allow you to..." is step 3, and I can't think of a plausible way to automate this. Probably better tested implicitly by continuous use.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter noted, the real challenge is step #3. The first 2 ones are solved by your SCM plugin and gradle task. You could try automating the last task by doing something like this

- identify the proper command line option, on your platform, that opens a specified intellij project from the command line
- find a simple good enough scenario that could validate that the generated project is working as it should. E.g. make a clean then build. Make sure you can reproduce these steps using keyboard shortcuts only. Validation could be made by validating either produced artifacts or test result reports, etc
- use an external library, like Robot, to program the starting of intellij and the running of your keyboards. [Here's a simple example with Robot](http://java.dzone.com/tips/write-your-own-custom). Use a dynamic language with inbuilt console instead of pure Java for that, it will speed your scripting a lot...
- Another idea would be to include a daemon plugin in intellij to pass back the commands from external CLI. Otherwise take contact with the intellij team, they may have something to ease your work here.

Notes:

- beware of false negatives: any failure could be caused by external issues, like project instability. Try to make sure you only build from a validated working project...
- beware of false positives: any assumption / unchecked result code could hide issues. Make sure you clean properly the workspace, installation, to have a repeatable state and standard scenario matching first use.

Final thoughts: while interesting from a theoretical angle, this automation exercise may not bring all the required results, i.e. the validation of the platform. Still it's an interesting learning experience and could serve as a material for a nice short talk, especially if you find out interesting stuff. Make it a beer challenger with your team when you have a few idle hours to try to see who can implement the fastest a working solution ;) Good luck!